# Add gradients to an object in Pixelmator?

Tags: gradient, shapes, pixelmator

I'm a new to graphic design and I'm whipping up a quick icon for an app kinda thing. I created a rounded rectangle shape.  Next I need to add a slight gradient to it to make it look neat.  I have to do the same with my text layer. How do you add a gradient to an object?

The method I tried was:

1. Layer options
2. Convert to pixels
3. Click to add gradient.

This method adds a gradient to the whole image. What should I really be doing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a selection, then apply the gradient to that.

Answer (score 1):

Using layer styles you can now add gradients to shapes quite easily. Have your tried doing that?

The guys in http://www.pixelmator.com have some good tutorials on layer styles.

We have also created a tutorial on layer styles here:
http://www.pixelmatortemplates.com/pixelmator-tip-14-introduction-to-layer-styles/

PN.